# How to filter a data frame

Tags: r, filter, r-faq

I have a data frame and tried to select only the observations I'm interested in by this:

```
data[data["Var1"]>10]
```

Unfortunately, this command destroys the `data.frame` structure and returns a long `vector`.

What I want to get is the `data.frame` shortened by the observations that don't match my criteria.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you go re-read http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf , but it actually doesn't have this information in it (to my surprise). Most of the other R introductions should, though ... e.g. pp. 36ff. of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf (see http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html generally)

Comment: I tried R-intro. icebreakeR looks good.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your statement.

Try this:

```
data[data[, "Var1"]>10, ]
```

Or:

```
data[data$Var1>10, ]
```

Or:

```
subset(data, Var1>10)
```

---

As an example, try it on the built-in dataset, `mtcars`

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars[mtcars[, "mpg"]>25, ]

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2


mtcars[mtcars$mpg>25, ]

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2

subset(mtcars, mpg>25)

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

Comment: Or: `data[data[["Var1"]]>10,]` ;-)

Comment: @mbq Indeed.  I have edited my answer to include some other options.

Comment: Or: `data[ unclass(subset(data,select=c("Var1")))[[1]]>10 , ]` !

Comment: surely you could make this a bit longer by putting, in, say, `identity(identity(identity(data)))` ...

Comment: Just for completeness, one could also try `data[data["Var1"] > 10, , drop = FALSE]`. drop works when the result is just one line/column and R tries to simplify it.

Answer (score 10):

Another method utilizing the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars %>%
        filter(mpg > 25)
```

Without the chain (%>%) operator:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(mtcars, mpg > 25)
```