# Filter by group project according selected variables

Tags: r

I have a data with

```
subject <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3)
RRT <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
SOFA <- c(8,9,2,10,12,11,19,8)
libo <- data.frame(subject,day,RRT,SOFA)
```

and I want to select data only from patients with RRT = 0 at day 1.
My desired output is

```
subject <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3)
day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
RRT <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1)
SOFA <- c(8,9,2,11,19,8)
libodesired <- data.frame(subject,day,RRT, SOFA)
```

How can I perform it without change from long to wide format? Is it possible with dplyr?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [*How to efficiently filter a data frame?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106330/2204410)

Answer (score 0):

You can use double `subset`:

```
subset(libo, 
       subject %in% subset(libo, RRT == 0 & day == 1)$subject)

  subject day RRT SOFA
1       1   1   0    8
2       1   2   0    9
3       1   3   1    2
6       3   1   0   11
7       3   2   1   19
8       3   3   1    8
```

- Select `subjects` according `RRT` and `day` (`subset(libo, RRT == 0 & day == 1)$subject`)
- Subset dataframe according selected subjects `subset(libo %in% SUBJECTS)`

Answer (score 0):

using the `tidyverse` and `dplyr`, you can select the subjects based on your criteria and join to subset your table

```r
subject<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
day<-c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3)
RRT<-c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)
SOFA<-c(8,9,2,10,12,11,19,8)
libo<-data.frame(subject,day,RRT,SOFA)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = TRUE)
libo %>%
  # select base on your criteria
  group_by(subject) %>%
  filter(RRT == 0 & day == 1) %>%
  select(subject) %>%
  # only keep rows from libo based on your subjects selection
  left_join(libo, by = "subject")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   subject [?]
#>   subject   day   RRT  SOFA
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       1     1     0     8
#> 2       1     2     0     9
#> 3       1     3     1     2
#> 4       3     1     0    11
#> 5       3     2     1    19
#> 6       3     3     1     8
```

Comment: It was perfect. Thank you. Just one more question: how can I create a new table with these values?

Comment: You can assign with `<-` as you have done to create the first dataframe.