# How do I find out specific details in a variable in R?

Tags: r

This is my dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews

There is a variable in there called 'countries'. Since it is categorical I have used `as.factor`  to break it down by countries.

```
wine$country <- as.factor(wine$country)
countries <- wine$country
count(countries)
plot(countries, xlab = "Countries", ylab = "Frequency")
```

This gives me 47 results and data too big to graph as it does not show all the countries.

So how do I amend the function to show me only countries over the freq > 1000.

I am brand new to R, so my apologies if this question has been asked. I am not sure even if I have framed it right

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106330/how-to-filter-a-data-frame

Comment: `wine_new <- wine[ave(wine$country, wine$country, FUN = length) > 1000, ]`